# Edits which change the scope of the original question getting approved

Tags: discussion, tagging, editing

Within a short time span I've suggested edits which [rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) the previous edit, which has gone through the review of an edit-process. This is because the initial edit has added a tag, which redefines the scope to a more narrow problem field. To be more specific, the tag [2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2013) has been edited to the tags of the original question, and as we've learned, this would limit the question to match the specification of

> For questions completely specific to all editions of SharePoint 2013 and **not past or future versions**

Examples: [1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/215921/revisions), [2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/216082/revisions) and [3](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/216077/revisions).

This seems to be a current trend of a particular user, but [not all of the edits are unnecessary](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/216071/revisions), so sure it's great we have revision activity in this community.

Now I'd put this question for the ones above 2k reputation and thus able to approve edits:

**Do you actually go through the suggested edit?** These misleading edits actually harm the questioner's chances of receiving help, so it's all but shrugs we should give for this matter.

Now this might be something which could be discussed on chat, but to have something to be answered on this meta question, I'd like to ask could this sloppy editing & approving be kept under control (& how)?

Comment: I agree, we must really see if edits are relevant. And as you say, the 2013 tag is one of the most abused ones on this site

Comment: I agree with you Moe. I have seen such edits. Thanks for bringing it up. I would be careful when reviewing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really appreciate your concern here moe. If you have the reputation, the only thing you can do is to edit the question back and remove the tag. I wish there's a way to see who approved the edits and who hasn't BEFORE you make your decision.

I can't say I'm 100% sure I haven't approved these kinds of edits in the past, but thanks for bringing it to our attention. I'll be more aware of it regardless if they come back up in the review list.

Answer (score 5):

I too really appreciate the question and suggestions by @Moe and @Mike.

I have reviewed more than 300 edits till now, I always reject those edits which are just not required or does not make post more effective.

When I am confused whether to approve or not, I always choose **`Skip`** option.

I believe having score more than 2000 is a kind of responsibility. You are now authorized and have some rights to make community better.

And for @Mike,

> I wish there's a way to see who approved the edits and who hasn't
>   BEFORE you make your decision

Yes there are way to see who has approved the edits. Even if you have not enough reputation you can see who has approved the edits.

Following are the steps:

**Step-1:** Just click on the name of the user who edited it. It will open a profile page as usual.

[image]

**Step-2:** Click on ** Activity** tab and then click on ***@@@ post edited** option.

[image]

**Step-3:** Click on **suggestions** tab and then select the question for which you want to see who has approved the edits and next click on **approved edit**.

[image]

**Step-4:** And here you can see the name of the person who has approved or rejected the edits.

[image]

If you are already aware about this then please ignore the steps :-)

Comment: That's true, but it's such a hassle going through all those steps instead of it being right there in the review pane. I appreciate your answer @Aakash

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Mike on the following, as it seems like the only action we currently are able to do:

> the only thing you can do is to edit the question back and remove the tag

Recently I've done some edits on questions, some of them obviously necessary, some for clarification and some which might have done a significant change on the body text although attempting to keep the scope and target of the question as they initially were. Most, *but not all* (which is great to see) of these edits were approved so we indeed have responsible reviewers here! That's a sign of a healthy reviewing process to me.

As the current workaround for the problem is somewhat manual and actual problem cases may happen due to lack of preventing guidance for users, I can only come up with actions which would require a change to the SE engine. Such preventing actions could be e.g.

- When a new privilege is earned, and the user is about to use it for the first time (whether it's editing or reviewing or something else), a pop-up would be shown:

  > *Are you aware of the guidance for the action-you-are-about-to-do? We suggest to go through this Help-documentation at first, pretty please!*
- A setting for "Announce when your edit has received a new revision" would be created and by default set to enabled